# generic method return type is map can also return object at sametime

Tags: java

I have the below interface

```
interface applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception;
}
```

below the class is the implementation of it

```
class CardvaletImpl<T> implements applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    private static final String Success = null;

    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
        T result = null;
         // put your logic 
        return result;
    }
}
```

and thats how the code will excecute from the caller class

```
CardvaletImpl<String> cardvaletImpl = new CardvaletImpl<>();
String result = cardvaletImpl.execute("JOBCODE");
```

now lets say if the above class has to return the map as shown in below scenario so advise me how i will put the map into result type which
is of generic type and will return the caller and how caller wil come to know that map is coming into the result object   as the interface is of generic type and the method in the interface returns object that is also of generic type

```
  class CardvaletImpl<T> implements applyBuisnessRule<T> {
    private static final String Success = null;

    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // ****Map that i want to return from this class to caller class *** 
    myMap.put("A",23);
    myMap.put("A",45);

    public T execute(String jobCode) throws Exception {
        T result = null;
         // ** advise how i will put the map into object that is into result and return to the caller

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't delete your question and then repost it. 10k+ users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50520831/putting-map-into-generic-object-type-and-returning-to-caller-back

Comment: `class CardvaletImpl implements applyBuisnessRule<Map<String,Integer>> { @Override public Map<String,Integer> execute(String jobCode) {...} }`

Comment: @jspcal thanks so it means i need to change the interface also

Comment: And another copy https://stackoverflow.com/q/50521141/18157

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Oracle's Java tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

> The ability of a subclass to override a method allows a class to inherit from a superclass whose behavior is "close enough" and then to modify behavior as needed. The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides. An overriding method can also return a subtype of the type returned by the overridden method. This subtype is called a covariant return type.

So, overriding method can't return super class of return type, only child class.